# SUMIF formula in VBA with two LastRow statements

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a formula that does a `SUMIF` with two lastrow statements. I have the following code, but I keep getting an error saying: Type mismatch.

```
LastRowStaff = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowExpense = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row

Range("F12").Formula = "=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ";" * Accrual * ";& L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"
```

The formula is based on the following formula in Excel, that does exactly what I want without the lastrow function.

```
=SUMIF(D42:D857;"*Accrual*";L42:L857)
```

What is wrong with my VBA code?

Comment: You are confusing local parameter identifiers with the `VBA` syntax. Change semi-colon to comma first. Then next thing is, to emulate a double quote through `VBA` you need to double-up > `""`. Best thing to do when not sure is to try to `Debug.Print` your formula first. Do you really need the formula in your cell? If you choose `VBA` then why not print the result and use `WorksheetFunction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you are confusing Excel syntax with VBA. You need to use comma instead of semi-colon, double-up your quotes and remove redundant `&` operators. Best is to `Debug.Print` your outcome before using it.

```
"=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ",""*Accrual*"",L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"
```

***Note1:*** Both `LastRowStaff` and `LastRowExpense` take their value from the implicit `ActiveSheet`. Consider using explicit sheet references.

***Note2:*** Also note that both last rows **need** to be the same, otherwise the formula will return an error. Therefor you would only really need to get just one last used row variable to minimize the chance of faulty formulas.